# Optimized loading to a hashtable in C#

Tags: c#, mobile, hashtable

This is kind of an open question for knowledge.

We have a file (currently CSV) which contains 800.000 strings.
We parse this file after loading in with string.split.
Then we put that string[] into a hashtable.

We have to use a hashtable due to us wanting to find specific strings in the hashtable within less then half a second (see it like auto correct suggesting words as fast as i start typing them, nearly instant after each keystroke).

This whole process has to run locally and on a tablet or phone. The process is taking too long as it is.

Is there any way we can optimize the current process? Or can we change the input file (like, have a prepared hashtable in a file somehow instead of the CSV) so it can directly put it back in memory when loaded in?

Any advice on speeding up this process in any way would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks oin advance,
Smiley

Comment: Why is it slow? Have you profiled to find the cause of the solution to be slow? If it is due to the hash function of the string calculating for a long time maybe you should rethink use of the hash use different hashing method (for instance only first n character hash)? If the strings in file are not changed or changed infrequently you can keep them sorted and retrieve them even faster with binary search then with hash table.

Comment: On PC we profiled it to be: read in file - 50ms, string split - 1000ms, to hashtable - 300ms. Which could be roughly x10 for all that on the tablet. Resulting in a long time.
What do you mean by them being sorted? (they are sorted already btw, how can that help us?)

Comment: To increase the speed either load it as a binary chunk, so use some serialisation technique, store the additional information (where string is split instead doing the split, store the pre-calculated string hash etc.) it really depends on your usage of file.

Comment: What is your key and value of your hastable?

Comment: How are you going to use a hash table to do autocomplete / autocorrect ? Shouldn't you be looking into using different data structures such as tries or the Aho Corasick algorithm to build data structures optimized for (incomplete) string matching? Once you have built such a dictionary, you can serialize it to files, and simply distribute that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flat files aren't used for a reason -- processing them is linear at best (and your case worse because you read them all, then split each one (already O(n^2) at worst), then sort them (another O(nlogn)) to insert into a hash table.

You'd be much better off with a DBMS, something like Sqlite, they store the hash table directly and are able to binary search (if properly indexed) right away, making lookups O(logn) with no setup cost. That cost is already paid when you create the database file.

Comment: So loading in the database file for a local database doesn't cost anything besides loading it in? (roughly that 50ms we use now) and is instantly available for the same search speed as a hashtable then? That might we what we want here.

Comment: Also, does this work on mobile somehow? (iOS/Android)

Comment: You are mistaking, you never want to load a database file in memory. That's the whole point of indexes, you load only them and then instantly know where to seek in the file to read the record. And yes, all mobile frameworks support Sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

There are already c# libraries that does that for you, without you needing to worry about optimization aspects

you can try :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Syntax example for Read:

```
void ReadCsv()
{
    // open the file "data.csv" which is a CSV file with headers
    using (CsvReader csv =
           new CsvReader(new StreamReader("data.csv"), true))
    {
        int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;

        string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();
        while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
                Console.Write(string.Format("{0} = {1};",
                              headers[i], csv[i]));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see further by standing in the shoulders of giants.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read input csv line by line and store each line immediately into hastable. String.Split don't perform well on big strings as it has to reallocate temp array many times.